# How to display info using Java AWT?

Tags: java, mysql, awt

I've developed an application using servlets, MySQL and Tomcat. I've been asked to create a version of this application that does not require the use of a server.

I've researching and I think that what I need is to create windows where I can show information to the user and to retrieve information from the users.

I've learned how to build windows by using Java AWT, and how to add buttons, lists... What I don't know how to do is to show the information stored in MySQL to the user.

If the user wants to visualice the content of one of the tables of the database I should show in the window a table showing the different rows and columns of the table.

How could I do it using AWT?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to suggest [JFC/Swing](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/). The Swing toolkit includes a rich set of components for building GUIs and adding interactivity to Java applications. Take a look at [JTable](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) component. Using JTable you can display tables of data.